# Using flatpages to create a simple facebook app, but CSRF problem caused by signed_request

Tags: django, facebook, csrf, django-flatpages

I am trying to create a simple, html-only facebook app for a client's fb page. I would like to use django's flatpages so that the client and his staff can change the content of the app through the django admin of their site. The problem is that Django returns a 403 "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." error when facebook attempts to send its own POST info and access the url of the app.

I already know about the @csrf_exempt decorator, but I am not sure how I would apply it to the flatpage view, as it is within the django.contrib code. Furthermore I would only want to disable csrf protection when the view is asked to call a specific facebook.html template (not not the default.html template). If there happened to be a {% crsf_exempt %} template tag for example, that would be perfect.

Can anyone think of a way to resolve this problem? Or maybe I should give up on the idea of using the django-flatpages to serve the facebook app?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this decorator on your views that are called facebook:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
```

this will disable csrf protection on that view.
Does this help?

Comment: Not quite. I reformulated the question. Thanks

Comment: the thing is that I want to use django_flatpages to make the facebook "canvas", but I don't know how I would add the @Crsf_exempt decorator to the flatpages view without messing with the django.contrib code. If I can't figure this out, I will probably just make my own django app and implement your solution on its view method.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem as you. I wanted to diable csrf for flatpages (but not for the rest of the site) and ended up with the following middleware:

```
class DisableCSRFOnFlatPages(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            FlatPage.objects.get(url=request.META.get('PATH_INFO'))
            setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
        except FlatPage.DoesNotExist:
            return
```

Add it to your settings and it should disable the csrf check whenever there's a flatpage.